# Perfect semi direct products

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, semidirect-product, group-extensions

Let $ \pi,V $ be a representation of a perfect group $ G $.

I'm interested in sufficient conditions for a semi direct product like $ V \rtimes_\pi G $ to be perfect.

Requiring that $ \pi $ is faithful and or irreducible isn't enough because of trivial counterexamples using abelian groups.

I'm especially interested in the condition that $ \pi $ is fixed point free (the only vector $ v $ fixed by all of $ G $ is the zero vector). Is that sufficient for $ V \rtimes_\pi G $ to be perfect?

Motivation: Let $ V $ be the $ n-1 $ dimensional vector space of length $ n$ binary vectors whose entries sum to 0. There is a natural permutation representation $ \pi $  of the alternating group $ A_n $ on $ V $. This representation is fixed point free, in fact it acts transitively on the nonzero vectors. For $ n \geq 5 $ the semdirecrt product $ V \rtimes A_n $ is perfect.

Consider the Weil representation of $ Sp_{2n}(p) $ on $ V=\mathbb{F}_p^{2n} $ for $ p $ an odd prime. This representation is fixed point free, in fact it acts transitively on the nonzero vectors. $ V \rtimes  Sp_{2n}(p) $ is perfect (except when $n=1,p=3 $ in which case the symplectic group is not perfect).

Is it good enough for $ \pi $ to be fixed point free? Or do we need that $ G $ is transitive on the nonzero elements of $ V $?

If you have some totally different sufficient condition for a semi direct product to be perfect feel free to share, these are just some thoughts.

And more generally I'm interested in any condition on a (possibly non split) extension of a perfect group $ G $
$$
1 \to V \to E \to G \to 1
$$
Which is sufficient to imply that $ E $ is perfect.

EDIT: Really nice sufficient condition from Derek Holt: Let
$$
1 \to V \to E \to G \to 1
$$
be a SES with $ V $ abelian and $ G $ perfect. Then if $ V $ is a (nontrivial) irreducible $ G $ module then $ E $ must be perfect. The statement for semi direct products is just the special case when the sequence splits.

Requiring nontriviality of the module just avoids the case that $ E $ is a direct product of $ G $ with a cyclic group of order $ p $, which is technically an irreducible $ G $ module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necessary and sufficient conditions for the semidirect product to be perfect are that $G$ is perfect (which you are assuming) and that the action of $G$ on $M/{\rm Rad}(M)$ is fixed point free. The second condition is equivalent to $M$ having no nontrivial homomorphisms onto the trivial module, or that the action of $G$ on ${\rm Dual}(M)$ is fixed point free.

It is not sufficient for the action of $G$ on $M$ to be fixed point free. For example, $A_5$ has a $5$-dimensional fixed point free module $M$ over ${\mathbb F}_2$, with a $4$-dimensional irreducible submodule $N$, and $M/N$ is the trivial module, so $M \rtimes G$ is not perfect.

Comment: Which five dimensional $ A_5 $ module over $ \mathbb{F}_2 $ are you thinking of? The one I'm familiar with is the standard permutation representation of $ S_5 $ on $ \mathbb{F}_2^5 $ restricted to $ A_5 $. That particular module is not fixed point free as $(1,1,1,1,1)$ is a nontrivial fixed point. However I'm sure there are many other modules to consider! So I'm curious to hear about this 5d fixed point free module you are thinking of!

Comment: One way to define it is to use the fact that $A_5 \cong {\rm PSL}(2,5)$ which has an action on six points. The corresponding $6$-dimensional permutation module $M$ over ${\mathbb F}_2$ does have the trivial module as a   one dimensional submodule $N$, and $M/N$ is the five dimensional module that I am thinking of.

Comment: Ah ok so the six points are the six lines (projective points) through $ (0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(1,0) $ respectively.  The trivial submodule $ N $ is generated by the formal sum of all six of these lines/projective points. Then any nonzero element of $ M/N $ corresponds to a formal sum which omits at least one point. So there is some transformation swapping a line in the sum with a line not in the sum. Thus nothing in $ M/N $ is a fixed point for all projective transformations.

Comment: Also the condition that a morphism to the trivial module must be trivial is satisfied by any module which is transitive on nonzero vectors. So if I understand you correctly then a representation $ \pi, V $ of a perfect group $G $ which is transitive on nonzero vectors should correspond to a perfect group $ V \rtimes_\pi G $ (this is a sufficient not a necessary condition). Asking more generally about short exact sequence $ 1 \to V \to E \to G \to 1 $, where $ V $ is abelian and $ G $ is perfect, is it sufficient for $ E $ to be perfect that $ G $ acts on $ V $ transitively on nonzero vectors?

Comment: Yes, in fact, if the action is transitive on nonzero vectors (provided that there is more than one nonzero vector), then the module must be irreducible and nontrivial, and that is a sufficient (but not neceessary) condition for the semidirect product to be perfect.

Comment: Oh that's great. So any irreducible representation of dimension more than 1 of a perfect group $ G $ leads a to a perfect semi direct product. I like that so much I might put it in an edit at the top of the question.

Comment: Does this imply that the affine special linear group $ ASL(n,q)= q^n \rtimes SL(n,q)  $ is perfect?( for all $ n $ and all $ q $ prime power such that $ SL $ is perfect (so that excludes $ SL(2,2), SL(2,3) $ )

Comment: Yes it does imply that.

Comment: wow my bad I got confused reading about the $ M/rad(M) $ and $ dual(M) $ stuff and didn't even read the comments that I was posting below! As you say if $ V $ is a nontrivial irrep of a perfect group $ G $ then $ V \rtimes G $ is always perfect.