# Is the affine special linear group perfect?

Tags: finite-groups, gap

The special linear group $ SL(n,q) $ is perfect, in fact quasisimple, for all $ n \geq 2 $ and $ q $ prime power with the exception of $ SL(2,2) \cong S_3 $ and $ SL(2,3)\cong 2.A_4 $. Is it the case that the affine linear group
$$
ASL(n,q) \cong q^n \rtimes SL(n,q)  
$$
is perfect for all $ n\geq 2 $ and $ q $ prime power with the exception of $ ASL(2,2) $ and $ ASL(2,3) $?

I've been looking at perfect groups in GAP of order less than 120,000 recently and there seem to be a lot of groups whose structure description looks like $ ASL(n,q) $.

If these are perfect I would be happy with a proof. I'd also just be happy with any information about how to easily program $ ASL(n,q) $ in GAP so I can just use IsPerfectGroup()

Comment: See your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438581/perfect-semi-direct-products).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I got carried away with the talk of $ M/rad(M) $ and dual modules being fixed point free (which is the correct way to phrase the necessary and sufficient condition). I should have read my own question more carefully! There is a very nice sufficient condition! If $ G $ is perfect and $ \pi:G \to GL(V) $ is irreducible then the semidirect product
$$
V \rtimes_\pi G
$$
is always perfect.